# Jquery Live Load - Load form via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply looking to call a function when a form is loaded via ajax.  My current code looks like this:

```
$('form').live("load",function() {...}
```

My ajax call looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({

                type: "get",
                url: "../design_form.php",
                data: "coll=App_Forms&form=Step_1_Company_Sign_Up",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html){                
                            jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);

                }   

        })
```

I know that i could put my call inside the success portion of the ajax call but i am trying to minimize code and resuse other codes so i would really like to use the live feature.

I am loading a form via ajax and when that form is loaded i want to trigger a function using the jquery live.  This works fine when i set it to "click"

```
$('form').live("click",function() {...}
```

but it is unnecessary to run this function on every click, i just need it to run once on the form load so that is why i want to use the load listener not the click.

Thank you.

Comment: Call .die inside .live so it will unbind after executing once. You should use .on if you are using jQuery 1.7.

Comment: There is no "load" function for live, the only way to do is through the success callback.

Comment: Can you answer the question in the "answer" space below that way i can give you a green check mark.  Also if you could provide an example of of where i am supposed to put the .die i would be very thankful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I think you wanted to have custom code inside success callback which will be used in different pages so you don't want to duplicate the same ajax call in different pages. If so, then you should call a function inside that success callback and implement different version of that in different page.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "../design_form.php",
            data: "coll=App_Forms&form=Step_1_Company_Sign_Up",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html){                
                  jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
                  afterFormLoad(); //Implement this function 
            }   

    });

    function afterFormLoad() { } //dummy function defined in the common code
```

And in your specific page,

```
    function afterFormLoad () {  
        //this is from page 1
    }
```

---

Below just shows you about `.live/.die` and `.one` incase if you want to understand how to unbind it using `.die`.

You can unbind `.live` inside the click handler using `.die`,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Dz3Ex/)

```
$('form').live("click",function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
   $('form').die('click'); // This removes the .live() functionality
});
```

You can use `.one` if you are using **jQuery 1.7**. See below code,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Dz3Ex/1/)

```
$(document).one('click', 'form', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I have posted a [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534630/8868582) related to it can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `load` to trigger with jQuery live, try to read the API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/live/

On the other hand, you can use a plugin called `livequery` and do something like this:

```
$(selector).livequery(function() { 
 
});
```

Use as reference:

- https://plugins.jquery.com/livequery
- https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

Comment: I have posted a [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534630/8868582) related to it can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a dom insert event.

Although, in javascript you can trigger *anything*

```
success: function(html){                
    jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000)
    .trigger('ajax-load');
}
```

Then you can listen to event using

```
jQuery('#Right_Content').on('ajax-load', callback);
```

Triggering the event manually might be helpful for use in a couple of pages, but if you need it to use across entire application, you'll be better using a plugin such as provided by Oscar Jara

Comment: I have posted a [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534630/8868582) related to it can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider load() method which is a convenience method of $.ajax

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
var data= "coll=App_Forms&form=Step_1_Company_Sign_Up"
jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().load("../design_form.php", data,function(){
            /* this is the success callback of $.ajax*/                      
            jQuery(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: I have posted a [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534630/8868582) related to it can you please check?